# Redis java api for inserting multiple values

Tags: java, redis

I have a csv file named abc.csv which contains data as follows :

> All,Friday,0:00,315.06,327.92,347.24
>
> All,Friday,1:00,316.03,347.73,370.55

and so on .....

I wish to import the data into Redis. How to do it through the Java API.
Please suggest the steps to do this.

I wish to run the jar and get the data imported into Redis db.
Any help on mass insert would also be helpful in case Java option is not possible.

Comment: Maybe http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/ will be the option for You

Comment: Need a simple java code to insert bulk data into redis so that later on it can be exposed as a jar. An example using jedis and pipeline will be useful if shared.

Comment: `Spring Boot` with 'spring-data-redis' and `Jedis` will do it for you. The comment of @Maciej Czarnecki is good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using Jedis(https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis), java client for redis. Just create a class with main method and create a connection, set keys.

```
void processData(){
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(
                    Paths.get("\Path\abc.csv"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    Jedis connection = new Jedis("host", port);
    Pipeline p = connection.pipelined();
    for(String line: lines){
        String key = getKey(line);
        String value = getValue(line);
        p.set(key,value);
    }
    p.sync();
}
```

If the file is big you can create an inputstream out of it and read line by line instead of loading the whole file. You should also than call p.sync() in batches, just keep a counter and do a modulo with batch size.

Comment: Got exception : redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: value sent to redis cannot be null

Comment: @Bullu1 key or value cannot be null, please do a null check or fix getKey and getValue in case they should not return null.

Answer (score 1):

[Redisson](https://redisson.org) allows to organize multiple commands to one. This called Redis pipelining. Here is example:

```
List<String> lines = ...

RBatch batch = redisson.createBatch();
RList<String> list = batch.getList("yourList");
for(String line: lines){
    String key = getKey(line);
    batch.getBucket(key).set(line);
}
// send to Redis as single command
batch.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jedis](https://github.com/redis/jedis?_ga=2.185606571.368052173.1624992100-559799179.1613634009) Lib. Here I have extended my Java Object to get key and Hash to set in the object. In your case, you can have a list of parsed CSV values and keys directly sent as a list.

```
private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;
public void setRedisHashInBatch(List<? extends RedisHashMaker> Obj) {

    try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
      log.info("Connection IP -{}", jedis.getClient().getSocket().getInetAddress());
      Pipeline p = jedis.pipelined();

      log.info("Setting Records in Cache. Size: " + Obj.size());
      int j = 0;
      for (RedisHashMaker obj : Obj) {
        p.hmset(obj.getUniqueKey(), obj.getRedisHashStringFromObject());
        j++;
        if (j == BATCH_SIZE) {
          p.sync();
          j = 0;
        }
      }
      p.sync();
    }
  }
```